# How to ensure that only authenticated users can read blobs in azure storage?

Tags: node.js, azure, storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to build some kind of instagram clone for me and my friends only. I'm using react in the frontend and node in the backend.

I'm also using azure to store the files my users upload. I've already manage to get Shared access signature (SAS), but I don't know if there's a more appropriate way to do this. Is generating a new SAS every time i want to show a post overkill? Is there a way to get a token so I can give an authenticated user read access to a container of blobs? So i dont have to make a sas for every blob.

At the moment, given a blob URL with valid sas token (not experired) in it, you can access the blob even in a browser with no login in my site.

Edit: To illustrate what I want to do here it is an example:
When you send some picture in a DM in twitter, you can try to get the URL of the picture. If you try to access that URL with incognito mode, you can't access that file. I can't find any resource on how to do something like that.

Comment: You're using SAS as designed. You can limit the lifetime of a SAS url if you want. You could also stream your blob content through your web front-end (but you'll pay the perf penalty, since your web app would be a new throttle point). Really up to you how you handle this.

Comment: Not really, i actually prefer @DavidMakogon approach. Thank you anyway